# Flask User Management : How to make Stateless Server using better authentication ways?

Tags: python, flask

- I have been reading at multiple places and it is suggested that the Web Servers should be **Stateles** with **share nothing architecture**. This helps them scale better.
- That means each request has all the information needed to process the request.
- This becomes tricky when you have **REST** endpoints that needs authentication.
- I have been looking at ways Flask extensions do this and [Flask Login](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Login/) extension is defined as

> Flask-Login provides user session management for Flask. It handles the
> common tasks of logging in, logging out, and **remembering your users’
> sessions** over extended periods of time.

- This seems like against the philosophy of building a **Stateless** server, isn't it?
- What are better ways to build a **Stateless** server with authentication provided via HTTP headers with Python or related python libraries?

P.S: Apologies for not posting a programming question here, this is a design issue and I do not know how to solve it and SO seems to have right people to answer such questions. Thanks.

Comment: actually session is just encrypted cookie for flask

Answer (score 3):

Flask-Login uses flask's [built in session management](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions), which by default uses secure/signed cookies, and so is purely client side.

It can support server side sessions if needed though of course, [here's](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/) an example redis backed session store.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem as you have said.
While I have built a simple solution for this but looking for a better one.
What I currently did is to ask the caller (Who send the http request) provide a 'X-User-Info' in the http header, the value is a token. When I received the request, I use this token to get user identity (From redis for instance) and all of the following authorization & permission control are based on this identity.
The authentication does nothing but generate a random token, save it with user info to redis and return the token itself to the caller.